# MYSQL - SET SESSION sql_mode = '';" - good idea?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-mode

I am thinking of the implications of setting the sql_mode=';' or sql_mode='' on session level.

Please, skip safety considerations of strict mode and it advantages.

Comment: So, if you want to skip all considerations, what's the point of asking this question?

Comment: I meant, why not set sql_mode to empty for sesssion if default is set, for example Reason no1: replication errors on diferents modes for master and slaves (its is set by session) etc. I'm not interested about that strict is safer, better, its constrain data type and its default....

Comment: About replication is the only reason i found, but i think that set it up in session is so tricky, and solves problem teporary - so is there another reasonst why not to do that ?